# python : TypeError: () takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def Check_InActive(Policy_Name):   
 with open ('Inactive_Policy_list.txt','r+') as p:  
  for word in p:  
   if (Policy_Name == word):  
    print (Policy_Name,word)  
    return "Inactive"  
  else:  
   return "Active"

Policy = raw_input("Enter Policy Name: ")  
Check_InActive(Policy)  
Flag = Check_InActive()  
if (Flag in "Inactive"):  
 print(Policy,"is ",Flag)
```

Can someone help me below error.

```
##    Flag = Check_InActive()
## TypeError: Check_InActive() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: You are not passing any argument to the function `Check_InActive` which is expecting `Policy_Name`

Comment: I want to pass "Policy" entered in raw input.

Comment: Your `Check_InActive` function takes one argument `Policy_Name` which is used here: `if (Policy_Name == word)`. However you are calling the function with no arguments here: `Flag = Check_InActive()`. So either make sure you are passing an argument or surround the code in your `Check_InActive` function with a `try` `except` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the argument to the `Check_InActive` functin. You should call it this way:

```
Policy = raw_input("Enter Policy Name: ")    
Flag = Check_InActive(Policy)  
if (Flag in "Inactive"):
    print(Policy,"is ",Flag)
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes i was trying to pass the argument in separate line and receiving the returned value in separate line.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide an argument to the function, and you don't need this call `Check_InActive(Policy)`, because you don't store the result

```
Policy = raw_input("Enter Policy Name: ")  
Check_InActive(Policy)  
Flag = Check_InActive(Policy)  
if (Flag in "Inactive"):  
    print(Policy,"is ",Flag)
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes i was trying to pass the argument in separate line and receiving the returned value in separate line. – Jagdish Mane just now   edit